# How To Find Minimal Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 \end{array}\right)$$

I know that the characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda-4)^3(\lambda-9)^2$
I know that the minimal polynomial can be a least $(\lambda-4)(\lambda-9)$ and $(\lambda-4)^3(\lambda-9)^2$ at most.

The matrix is $\text{diagonal}(J_2(4),J_1(4),J_1(9),J_1(9))$

How can I continue?

Comment: You can always just check all options

Comment: @asdf I am looking for a better way

Answer (score 3):

We have

$(A-4I)e_1 = 0$

$(A-4I)e_2 = e_1 \ne 0 $ and $(A-4I)^2 e_2=0$.

$(A-4I)e_3 = 0$

$(A-9I)e_4 = 0$

$(A-9I)e_5 = 0$

Therefore, $(A-4I)(A-9I)\ne0$ but $(A-4I)^2(A-9I)=0$.

Thus, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(\lambda-4)^2(\lambda-9)$.

Comment: How did you get to $V_4= \langle e_1,e_2,e_3 \rangle$ and  $V_9= \langle e_4,e_5\rangle$? you looked at Null(A-4I) and Null(A-9I)?

Comment: @newhere, the matrix has clearly two blocks, which correspond to invariant subspaces. But, yes, looking the kernels works too.

Comment: But $null(A-4I)=2$ and $null(A-9I)=2$ why just 2 blocks? Jordan block has ones on the diagonal above the main diagonal

Comment: @newhere, right, I meant, generalized eigenspaces.

Answer (score 2):

The minimal polynomial has a factor $(x - \lambda)^m$ if the largest block with the eigenvalue $\lambda$ in the Jordan form is of the size $m\times m$.

In your case, the size of the largest block with the eigenvalue $4$ is $2\times 2$, and the size of the largest block with the eigenvalue $9$ is $1\times 1$.

Hence the minimal polynomial is $$(x-4)^2(x-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

The given matrix is a block diagonal matrix with blocks $\begin{bmatrix} 4&1 \\ &4\end{bmatrix}$, a $2\times 2$ block, followed by the $1\times 1$ blocks, $[4]$, $[9]$, $[9]$. Multiplication and addition can be done "on the blocks". A polynomial annihilates (by the obvious action) $A$, iff it does it for/on each block.

So we are searching for the minimal (polynomial,) divisor of the characteristic polynomial $(X-4)^3(X-9)^2$ which kills all blocks. The first block is killed by $(X-4)^2$. The next ones respectively by $(X-4)$, $(X-9)$, $(X-9)$. The lowest common multiple of them is 
$$(X-4)^2(X-9)\ .$$